# Programmatically resize extended partition to fill the entire drive

Tags: linux, partitioning, script, mbr

After restoring a cloned OS image on a disk of arbitrary size (larger than that of the original image was captured from), I would like the *extended* partition in the MBR table to include all the available disk space so that new *logical* partitions could be added. The questions is how to accomplish this with a command line utility — without using interactive programs (especially those that have a GUI, like GParted) and, possibly, without inventing the wheel via sophisticated shell script that parses the output of `fdisk` and alike.

The simpliest method I found available in Linux text console is this:

1. Use `cfdisk` TUI to interactively create a *logical* partition (automatically snapped to free space beyond existing *extended* partition), write the changes and exit.
2. Use `fdisk` shell to interactively delete that newly created *logical* partition, write the changes and exit.

(It is only at the “write and exit” step of `fdisk` that the *extended* partition is resized — in order to fix the discrepancy, I guess: if the *logical* partition is deleted by `cfdisk` itself, then *extended* partition turns out to have unaltered size.)

The tools I tried that are not a direct answer to my question, and why:

- `cfdisk` — not scriptable, does not actually adjust the *extended* partition size (at least when temporary *logical* partition is deleted; see above);
- `fdisk` — does not allow to create *logical* partitions outside of the *extended* partition;
- `parted` — scripting-friendly, but requires specifying exact start and end sectors (well, the last sector may be entered as `-1s`), and seems to behave like `fdisk` — at least I could not figure out valid start sector number, always receiving “Can't have overlapping partitions” error, even when passing in the values previously selected by `cfdisk` in default mode;
- `gdisk` — just converts the MBR partition table to GPT, which is not an option for me;
- `sfdisk` — dedicated to re-creating the entire partition table from scratch, so no different than invoking `fdisk` for the same exsessive set of actions.

I think this is a common task to adjust the size of extended partition, but surprisinlgy enough could not find any pre-existing solution.